# Json.Net, how to create json dynamically by path?

Tags: c#

I'm new to Json.net, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right / best way, but I can't figure this out:

I'm creating an output JObject:

```
JObject joOutput = new JObject();
```

Now, I have a list of paths to values:

```
a.b.c = 5
a.b.d = 7
a.c.q = 8
```

So I want to populate the joOutput object in the obvious way using that hierarchy.

I can't seem to find a way to set the value by path, obviously creating the path along the way if it doesn't exist.

I'm trying to split the path on the .'s and create the nodes, but I can't even get that far as the api is very confusing.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you plan on using `joObject` for that can't be done with `a` ?

Comment: @JamesCurran with a what?

Comment: With the object `a`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string a = @"{""b"": {""c"":5, ""d"":7}, ""c"": {""q"":8}}";
JObject joObject = JObject.Parse(a);
```

UPDATE:

```
var B = new JObject();
B.Add("c", 5);
B.Add("d", 7);

var C = new JObject();
C.Add("q", 8);


JObject A = new JObject();
A.Add("b", B);
A.Add("c", C);
```

UPDATE2, for completeness, here is Vladimir's method:

```
var B = new Dictionary<string, int> { ["c"] = 5, ["d"] = 7 };
var C = new Dictionary<string, int> { ["q"] = 5, ["8"] = 7 };
var A = new Dictionary<string, object> { ["b"] = B, ["c"] = C };

var AA = JObject.FromObject(A);
```

Comment: I need to create it DYNAMICALLY, that was just an example set. It might be a.q.z on the next run. I just get a list of paths and I need to create the json from that.

Comment: @SledgeHammer you do realize that you can put that string together however you want, right?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, the whole point was to use the API instead of creating the string myself.

Comment: Ah, I see what the issue was... I was using the JObject incorrectly. I was assuming the name was a property of the object and its not. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to solve your problem by using Dictionary with string key and object value.

```
Dictionary<string,object> myJsonObj = new Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Each element inside can be also same dictionary.

Comment: myJsonObj.Add("subElement", new Dictionary<string, object>); myJsonObj["subElement"].Add("subsubElement", 1);

Comment: After serialization it will be {"subElement" : { "subsubElement" : 1 } }