# Create a New Json File with Properties Pulled From Another File Using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What I'm trying to do is grab some Properties and sub-Properties from a .json file to create a new json file.  Let's say I have a file....

```json
    {
      "One": {
         "SomeProp": "SomeValue"
      },
      "Two": {
         "SomeProp2": "SomeValue2",
         "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
      },
      "Three": {
         "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
      },
      "Four": {
         "SomeProp4": "SomeValue4"
      }
    }
```

What I want is a new .json file with only `Two` and its sub-Properties and `Three` and Property in it...

```json
{
  "Two": {
     "SomeProp2": "SomeValue2",
     "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
  },
  "Three": {
     "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
  }
}
```

So far, I'm cycling through the file like this...

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(firstJsonFile);

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var property in jsonObject.Properties())
{
    if (property.Name == "Two" || property.Name == "Three")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(property.Name);

        // Cycle through sub-Properties...
        foreach (var subProperty in ((JObject)property.Value).Properties())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(subProperty.Name + "-> " + subProperty.Value.Type);           
        }       
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to get the Main Property + sub-Properties I'm collecting above written to a separate json file?  And how do I ensure the correct sub-Property.Value.**Type** is written to the new file?

I need this for saving and restoring values for an application and it has to be dynamic in that we can't hard code the data model.

I'm starting to play around with System.Text.Json to see if that will help. It seems it might, but I'm not really getting anywhere with it.

Is this possible?

Comment: [How to write a JSON file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16921652/215552) See also [Json.Net, how to create json dynamically by path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44076294/215552)

Comment: Not to mention [Json.Net's own documentation with hundreds of samples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteToJsonFile.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be dynamic. So let's say you parse `propertiesToSave` from an external source such as a file or user interface. Then `newJsonObject` is created with the specified properties.

```
var propertiesToSave = new string[] { "Two", "Three" };
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var newJsonObject = new JObject();
foreach (var propertyToSave in jsonObject.Properties().Where(p => propertiesToSave.Contains(p.Name)))
    newJsonObject.Add(propertyToSave);
```

To get the new json you can do `string newJson = newJsonObject.ToString();`

```json
{
  "Two": {
    "SomeProp2": "SomeValue2",
    "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
  },
  "Three": {
    "SomeProp3": "SomeValue3"
  }
}
```

Finally save `newJson` as a file. The code depends on .Net version you're using. Check [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16921652/215552) provided by Heretic Monkey.